# Assign RecentlyViewed SOQL query to List

Tags: userlicense, recentlyviewed

I'm trying to query the recentlyviewed records for a user in a login flow. When I run the following query I receive this error: "`Compile Error: Illegal assignment from List<RecentlyViewed> to List<recentlyViewed>`"
Query:

```
List<RecentlyViewed> listRV = [SELECT
                    Alias
                    ,Email
                    ,FirstName
                    ,Id
                    ,IsActive
                    ,LastName
                    ,LastReferencedDate
                    ,LastViewedDate
                    ,Name
                    ,Phone
                    ,ProfileId
                    ,Title
                    ,Type
                    ,UserRoleId
                FROM
                    RecentlyViewed ];
```

This is a standard object in Salesforce. Here is the SOAP API link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm

Comment: Additional Note:

I tried moving the query to a collection variable in the flow and then passing the collection variable to apex. Here is the error I received: "InvocableMethod methods do not support parameter type of List<List<recentlyViewed>> at line 3"
Code:

Comment: public class recentlyViewed {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void getRecentlyViewed(List<List<RecentlyViewed>> flowCollection) {
        List<List<RecentlyViewed>> flowRecentlyViewedRecords = new List<List<recentlyViewed>>();
        flowRecentlyViewedRecords = flowCollection;

        List<RecentlyViewed> newRecentlyViewRecords = new List<RecentlyViewed>();
        List<List<RecentlyView>> newRecentlyViewLists = new List<List<RecentlyView>>();

Comment: for (List<RecentlyViewed> listRV : flowCollection) {
            for (RecentlyViewed rv : listRV) {
                        RecentlyViewed__c newRV = new RecentlyViewed__c();
                        newRV.Alias__c = rv.Alias;
                        newRV.Email__c = rv.Email;
                        newRV.FirstName__c = rv.FirstName;
                        newRV.Id__c = rv.Id;
                        newRV.IsActive__c = rv.IsActive;
                        newRV.LastName__c = rv.LastName;
newRV.LastReferencedDate__c = rv.LastReferencedDate;

Comment: newRV.LastViewedDate__c = rv.LastViewedDate;
                        newRV.Name__c = rv.Name;
                        newRV.Phone__c = rv.Phone;
                        newRV.ProfileId__c = rv.ProfileId;
                        newRV.Title__c = rv.Title;
                        newRV.Type__c = rv.Type;
                        newRV.UserRoleId__c = rv.UserRoleId;
                        newRecentlyViewRecords.add(newRV);
            }
            newRecentlyViewLists.add(newRecentlyViewRecords);
        }  
    }
}

Comment: sorry for the multiple posts for the code

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of using comments.